# Get id of element in the iteration with jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2

It is best for the code to explain the question.

```
<s:iterator value="collection" status="stat">
...
<input 
  id="sendEmailButton${stat.count}" 
  value="<s:text name="label.send.email"/>" 
  type="button" 
  data-action="sendEmail"/>
...
</s:iterator>

...
<script>
...
$(function(){
  $('#sendEmailButton').unbind('click');
...
  });
</script>
```

How to get that particular button in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `attribute starts with selector`..

```
$('[id^="sendEmailButton"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The *starts with* selector works just fine. If you want another alternative you can select by your data-action attribute:

```
$('input[data-action=sendEmail]')
```